# Is it bad form to extend inherent types in a library?

Tags: types, rust, traits, monkeypatching

I have a function `downsample_vec` that takes a `Vec` and removes some of its values based on their positions. I had trouble annotating the right traits (I only needed `Clone` and `Index`, but couldn't make it work), so I decided to use `self` to see if I could convince the compiler to make the right inferences:

```
impl Vec<IndexMut<usize>> {
    fn downsample<usize>(&mut self, factor: usize) {
        let len = self.len();
        if factor > len {
            self.clear(); // downsample factor skips all elements
        } else if factor == 1 {
            return; // no actual downsampling
        }

        for ind in 0..len() {
            if ind % factor != 0 {
                self.remove(ind);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the compile error `` the value of the associated type `Output` (from the trait `std::ops::Index`) must be specified [E0191] ``.

I'm not exactly sure how to specify the output type, and didn't find any references on how to do this, just blogs on traits in general. My main resource was [the rust vec `.retain()` source](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/4b89debc7b776a947331dd0ceaa52ba8476157b2/src/libcollections/vec.rs#L666).

Is it bad form to locally monkeypatch `Vec` like this in a specific library in the first place, or is there a right way to do this? (The original separate function I wrote is viewable in [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=10484030e7ab5768c9117c675d128f41&version=stable&backtrace=2)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things about your code.

First, you can't write an `impl`-block for a type you are not defining in your own crate. The best you can do is to define a new trait and then implement that trait for foreign types. This is something that is common practice and often called "extension trait", using the naming scheme `*Ext`, like for example [`MetadataExt`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/linux/fs/trait.MetadataExt.html). So we can build it like so:

```
trait DownsampleExt {
    fn downsample(&mut self, factor: usize);
}
```

Now we have to implement it for `Vec`. In your code you use the `IndexMut` trait as if you want to make sure the vector itself is mutably indexable. But since `Vec` is already a concrete type (or rather type constructor), the compiler already knows that it is mutably indexable. So this already works:

```
impl<T> DownsampleExt for Vec<T> {
    fn downsample(&mut self, factor: usize) {
        // action code
    }
}
```

If the `DownsampleExt` trait is in scope, you can call `downsample` on any `Vec` object.

Your action code, however, still contains a few bugs/has a few problems:

- You said "that takes a Vec and returns a copy of it with fewer values", but the code you gave us mutates the vector instead of creating a copy! Be aware that your description doesn't match your code.
- You don't check for `factor == 0`
- Your `for` loop doesn't work: when we remove elements while iterating over the indices, the invalidate the indices. Whenever you remove one element you mustn't increase the index in that iteration.
- Also note that your algorithm runs in O(n²), because `remove` is a linear time algorithm. This might not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the function description issue. I had done too many edits and tweaks to the question as I messed with it.